# How can I understand this word "passively" in this paragragh?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context

One of the keys to insects’ successful survival in the open air lies in
their outer covering — a hard waxy layer that helps prevent their tiny
bodies from dehydrating. To take oxygen from the air, they use narrow
breathing holes in the body-segments, which take in air **passively** and
can be opened and closed as needed. Instead of blood contained in
vessels, they have free-flowing hemolymph, which helps keep their
bodies rigid, aids movement, and assists the transportation of nutrients
and waste materials to the appropriate parts of the body. The nervous
system is modular — in a sense, each of the body segments has its
own individual and autonomous brain — and some other body systems
show a similar modularization. These are just a few of the many ways
in which insect bodies are structured and function completely
differently from our own.
[Original text](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=nhfcDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA7&lpg=PA7&dq=%22each%20of%20the%20body%20segments%20%3E%20has%20its%20own%20individual%20and%20autonomous%20brain%22&source=bl&ots=bwBMS1Uafp&sig=ACfU3U3yQcZ-0Z_C4KeC5xaRVVTOhCkqgA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiEwv-mjLXzAhWOZt4KHWbbC_kQ6AF6BAgPEAM#v=onepage&q&f=false)

I searched for the word in Cambridge Dictionary.

> in a way that does not act to influence or change a situation; in a
> way that allows other people to be in control:

I want to know if this passively means **automatically** or **manually**. I think these two words can't be interchangeable in this context.

1. (In my opinion) If the meaning is toward **automatically**, it means the insect isn't conscious of breathing holes, which can open and close independent of insect.
2. (In my opinion) If the meaning is toward **manually**, It means the insect is conscious of a variable surrounding environment (e.g oxygen content), so it opens or closes the breathing hole for its survival depending on the surrounding.

Comment: I think the meaning is that insects don't have lungs or ribs and can't actively breathe air in and out as mammals do.

Answer (score 1):

I understand this to mean that insects do not have muscles for breathing. If I'm right, air moves in and out of the breathing holes on its own because of some other processes(es) happening in side the waxy layer.

While "automatically" and "manually" are opposite, they both refer to how some overt process happens. In this case, *there is no overt process*, so "passively" is a third option, and the correct one.

If I put cloth in water, the cloth absorbs the water passively, not automatically. This is the same.